# ¿Cuándo usar "coste" y cuándo "costo"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

Ambas tienen un significado parecido, ¿cuándo se debe usar una o la otra?

> [coste](http://dle.rae.es/coste)
>
> 2 . m. Gasto realizado para la obtención o adquisición de una cosa o de un servicio.
>
> [costo](http://dle.rae.es/costo)
>
> 1 . m. Cantidad que se da o se paga por algo.

Comment: Interesante. Raro lo que da el DRAE: el significado 1 de coste es un enlace a →costa; de ahí, el significado 1 es →costo. Parecen ser sinónimos. Nunca he oido la segunda palabra, sin embargo, y rara vez la he leido.

Comment: @c.p. yo tambien nunca habia visto "coste" solo costo, apenas hace unos días la vi dentro de la aplicacion web de Google Adwords.

Comment: En España es mucho más común "coste" que "costo".

Comment: I'd say that "coste" is the most appropriate; "costo" is in disuse nowadays (except when talking about drugs... but that's a different thing)

Comment: I am from Nicaragua and we say "costo" in any context.

Comment: I am from Cuba and I've heard `coste` & `costo`, I've never used `costa`

Comment: Soy de Puerto Rico y, desde que nací, siempre he escuchado "costo" al referirse al precio de venta o cantidad pagada por algún artículo o servicio.

Comment: One thing is true... Spanish people tends to say what they say is correct, others ways are old fashioned or just wrong, there is a phenomenon though "centro-periferia": periferia tends to maintain and use old correct forms; new ones many times come after misuse, for instance RAE accepted "azúcar" as masculine because Spanish people thinks it is because it is said "el aúcar", like "el arma, el hambre" all feminine, still in Andalucía and America you use "azúcar morena" and not "moreno". And costo is only taken by hashish in Spain, not in America

Comment: Una cosa... los españoles tienden a decir que ellos dicen lo correcto, las otras formas son arcaicas o directamente erróneas. Hay un fenómeno lingüístico llamado "centro-periferia": la periferia mantiene y usa formas correctas antiguas; las nuevas suelen darse por mal uso, p. e. la RAE aceptó "azúcar" como masculino porque los españoles lo creen porque lleva el artículo masculino delante en "el azúcar", otras formas como "el arma, el hambre" son femeninas también. Aún en Andalucía y América se dice "azúcar morena" y no "moreno". Y costo sólo es hashish en España, no en América.

Answer (score 7):

I would say "coste" is more spanish and "costo" (not refering drugs) is more latinoamerican.
Like Juan Luis Guerra says in his song "el costo de la vida..." refering to "lo que cuesta la vida" :)

Comment: I think both answers are right, but +1 for the aclaration for the non-spanish speakers: "costo" also means "hachís" (drug) in spanish.

Comment: I've never heard that use of "costo", it should be a regionalism. On the other hand, it will be clear from the context you are not refering to a slang for "drugs".

Answer (score 5):

Both are synonyms, but you can expect "coste" to be used in a more "technical" environment, like when you're managing budgets for a project or an enterprise. I've read that in memos from the logistic department for example. As you can see from the definition, you use it mostly for thinks related to money.

Oh the other hand, "costo" if the normal word in an informal context.

For example:

> Los costes/costos de los nuevos equipos serán compensados por un
> incremento en la eficiencia de producción.

Both statements sound good, but

> El costo del éxito es el esfuerzo. (sounds good)
>
> El coste del éxito es el esfuerzo. (sounds bad)

In any case, people will understand both.

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de que la pregunta estaba en Español, espero haberme explicado bien en inglés.

Comment: Yo soy de España y "El coste del éxito..." me suena bien, más bien es la de "El costo..." la que me suena extraña. En el caso de la primera frase emplearía también costes antes que costos. La verdad es que, al menos por mi zona, costo no se oye casi nunca en este ámbito.

Comment: OK, no lo imaginaba. Hay que agregar la etiqueta de "diferencias regionales" entonces. ¿Es así en todo España? ¿Alguien que pueda dar luces sobre otros países de América?

Comment: No sé en otras partes de España, yo te hablo desde Valencia y supongo que es igual en toda la zona de levante.