# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "a toda costa" y "a todo costo"?

Tags: género

Me parece que las frases son diferentes. ¿Nunca son intercambiables o a veces sí es posible?

Buscando en Google, puedo ver que mayormente "a todo costo" aparece en contratos pero también hay resultados así:

- “Han querido silenciarme a todo costo” - La Nación
- "Chavismo acordó
  en secreto impedir el revocatorio a todo costo"

Eso me ha confundido. ¿Alguien me puede explicar?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cuándo usar “coste” y cuándo “costo”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4748/5481)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a toda costa** se refiere a lograr algo sin importar los esfuerzos que se deban invertir en ello.

**a todo costo** se refiere más bien a costos económicos, por ejemplo, una cláusulas en un contrato bien podría decir  *a todo costo incurrido, se le aplicará una tasa no menor al 5% contra comisiones*

Es probable, sin embargo, que  en algunas regiones *todo costo* no tenga la connotación económica (como parece ser el caso en Venezuela ).

También podría ser el caso de que se tratase de un astuto juego de palabras, donde el editor de los encabezados quiere subrayar que quienes trataban de detener el referendos, arriesgaban solamente su dinero, sin consecuencias más allá de las económicas.

Answer (score 4):

La única frase que aparece como tal en el diccionario de la RAE es "a toda costa":

> [**a toda costa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B6A1o8v)
>
> 1. loc. adv. Sin limitación en el gasto o en el trabajo.

En Argentina nunca he oído "a todo costo" sino "a cualquier costo", que suele conllevar un aspecto económico no siempre presente en "a toda costa".

Google ngram arroja esta comparación en la frecuencia de uso entre "a todo costo" y "a cualquier costo":

[image: ngram]

Comment: +1 por el uso de BigData. No hay como la evidencia respaldada por conjuntos de datos matemáticamente analizable!!